# I'm trying to add input text into a list but doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, function

So I'm trying to put input text into a list but doesn't work. And empty list option doesn't work either. Here is my code:

http://pastebin.com/knL8dL5y

Here is the task I was given: 
Create a " numeric keypad " by putting out 10 buttons with text 0,1,2,3 etc . Make as
a text field where you can enter numbers as 3604 by pressing the buttons. Every time you
press a button , should therefore number that is on the button is added to the text box.

Somehow it doesn't let me add the numbers to another list and it won't empty the list either.

Comment: Please include code examples in the body of the question

Comment: 1. Your button `btnAddList` has a capital L, but your javascript `onclick` event has a lowercase L - Javascript is case-sensitive. Should be `document.getElementById("btnAddList").onclick = addList;`   2. Make sure to change your second `<li>` tag to be `</li>`  **Working JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/o7jdrh95/

Comment: It says: "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon." I don't really know why it says this. (first time here)

Comment: @TylerRoper thx. But my emptyList button still doesn't work.

Comment: @TylerRoper nvm. It works now. Thank you all.

Comment: @MyNameIsNotYourConcern It is because you're using `...("text1").innerHTML` instead of `...("text1").value`. Updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o7jdrh95/1/  **EDIT:** Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

This is working,check it out:

```
<script>

        function add(num) {
            var calc = document.getElementById("text1");
            calc.value += num;
        }

        addList=function() {
            var name = document.getElementById("text1").value;
    alert(name);
                document.getElementById("liste").innerHTML = document.getElementById("liste").innerHTML + "<li>" + name + "</li>";
                //document.getElementById("liste").innerHTML = "";
        }


        var emptyList=function() {
            document.getElementById("text1").value = "";
        }  

        kappa=function() {
            document.getElementById("btnAddList").onclick = addList;
            document.getElementById("btnEmptyList").onclick = emptyList;
        }
        window.onload = kappa //When the site is fully loaded
</script>
```

Now the html:

```
List:   <input type="text" id="text1" />
<button type="button" id="btnAddList">Add list</button>
<button type="button" id="btnEmptyList">Empty list</button>
<br/>
<button id="btnAdd1" onclick="add(1)">1</button>
<button id="btnAdd2" onclick="add(2)">2</button>
<button id="btnAdd3" onclick="add(3)">3</button>
<button id="btnAdd4" onclick="add(4)">4</button>
<button id="btnAdd5" onclick="add(5)">5</button>
<button id="btnAdd6" onclick="add(6)">6</button>
<button id="btnAdd7" onclick="add(7)">7</button>
<button id="btnAdd8" onclick="add(8)">8</button>
<button id="btnAdd9" onclick="add(9)">9</button>
<button id="btnAdd0" onclick="add(0)">0</button>

<ol id="liste">
```

Comment: Thank you so much! but I have finding the problem with empty list button. I had the element on the text instead of the list. But it works now. Thank you so much anyways.

Comment: You are most welcome.If this solved your issue then mark this as correct answer.